# Set font for matplotlib ticks

Tags: matplotlib

I want the ticks in matplotlib to be typeset using Computer Modern sans-serif. How do I do this?

I would have expected this would do the trick, but it doesn't:

```
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'computer modern sans serif'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = ['computer modern']
```

The font.family property has five values:

1. 'serif' (e.g., Times),
2. 'sans-serif' (e.g., Helvetica),
3. 'cursive' (e.g., Zapf-Chancery),
4. 'fantasy' (e.g., Western), and
5. 'monospace' (e.g., Courier).

After setting the font family you provide a list of fonts for matplotlib to try to find in order.